# Shuffle Stage Failing Due To Executor Loss

Tags: apache-spark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

I get the following error when my spark jobs fails `**"org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: The relative remote executor(Id: 21), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead."**`

Over view of my spark job

input size is ~35 GB

I have broadcast joined all the smaller tables with the mother table into say a `dataframe1` and then i salted each big table and `dataframe1` before i join it with `dataframe1` (left table).

profile used:

```
@configure(profile=[
     'EXECUTOR_MEMORY_LARGE',
     'NUM_EXECUTORS_32',
     'DRIVER_MEMORY_LARGE',
     'SHUFFLE_PARTITIONS_LARGE'
])
```

using the above approach and profiles i was able to get the runtime down by 50% but i still get **Shuffle Stage Failing Due To Executor Loss** issues.

is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: It looks like you are substantially increasing your compute cost. For your input size, this feels like it should be a problem with your code, maybe you're having some join explosion, execution heavy udfs, or other similarly complex code, normally refactoring the code into simpler steps is the answer here.

Comment: @fmsf i have salted all the bigger tables (rows > 1 million) and then join them, this was to avoid skew joins, all my tables are left joined to main df. Is there a way i can find where the data is exploding?

Comment: It may be spark also failing to optimize your query, and ending up with a very big query plan. You  I would recommend trying to break it into steps, maybe use checkpoints as well if you can. What you are describing is more of a spark question, not necessarily a foundry one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple things you can try:

1. Broadcast Joins: If you have used broadcast hints to join multiple smaller tables, then the resulting table (of many smaller tables) might be too huge to be accommodated in each executor memory. So, you need to look at total size of dataframe1.
2. 35GB is really not huge. Also try the profile "EXECUTOR_CORES_MEDIUM", which really increases the parallelism in data computation. Use Dynamic allocation (16 executors should be fine for 35GB) rather than static allocation. If 32 executors are not available at a time, the build doesn't start. "DRIVER_MEMORY_MEDIUM" should be enough.
3. Spark 3.0 handles skew joins by itself with Adaptive Query Execution. So, you need not use salting technique. There is a profile called "ADAPTIVE_ENABLED" with foundry that you can use. Other settings of adaptive query execution, you will have to set manually with "ctx" spark context object readily available with Foundry.

Some references for AQE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/aqe
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#adaptive-query-execution

Comment: adding EXECUTOR_CORES_MEDIUM helped improve parallelism, thank you for this.